# Fluid, centered content block with sidebar

Tags: responsive-design, center, fluid-layout

I'm pulling my hair here. Trying to come up with a simple responsive layout where two fluid boxes are aligned next to each other. The main box must always be centered in the browser window, while the other should be aligned beside it in its top right corner. See example image below -

[image]

Tried different approaches involving negative percentages and three-column faux layouts but it just doesn't work.

Comment: This boxes have a fixed or dynamic width?

Comment: Dynamic width. Sorry if that wasn't clear enough, but for me fluid = dynamic.

Comment: So check the answer and the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Demo: http://dabblet.com/gist/7201560

Markup:

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='main-col'></div>
    <div class='right-col'></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
        text-align: center;
        }

    .main-col, .right-col {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
        text-align: left;
        margin-right: -4px; /* css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/‎ */
        }

    .main-col { 
        width: 50%;
        margin-left: 20%; /* equal to .right-col's width */            
        }

    .right-col {
        width: 20%;
        }
```

What's happening here:

The centered main column and right column have `display: inline-block`, and they're centered in the viewport by giving their container `text-align: center`. They're still not centered the way you want though. Since they're sibling elements you can use margin to push the main column to the left with a value equal to right-column's width, essentially centering itself.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can check my try in this link http://jsfiddle.net/WHq8U/17/.

I had to use a little jquery to calculate the sidebar `absolute position`. Let me know your opinion about this.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Danko, though I'd prefer not to use positioning and javascript to accomplish this.